# RandomizedSearchCV with xgboost classifier is taking too long

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, cross-validation

I am trying to run this code on my dataset. However, its taking too long (the code has been running since yesterday and my dataset is not too large)

```
# A parameter grid for XGBoost
params = {
        'min_child_weight': [1, 5, 10],
        'gamma': [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5],
        'subsample': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        'max_depth': [3, 4, 5]
        }
```

```
xgb_classifier = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=600,
 objective='binary:logistic',silent=True, nthread=1)
folds = 3
param_comb = 5
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle = True, random_state = 1001)

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb_classifier, param_distributions=params,
 n_iter=param_comb, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=4, cv=skf.split(trainx,trainy),
 verbose=3, random_state=1001 )

random_search.fit(trainx, trainy)
```

I am new in the field. any ideas?

Comment: can you remove nthread and change n_jobs=-1

Comment: no it didn't work .. +12 hours of running and then gave me a warning `UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.`